# Cosmos DB - 5 RU writes possible?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In the [docs on optimizing operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/optimize-cost-reads-writes) in Cosmos DB, it lists the following:

> Cost of one write, 1KB = 5 RU

Under what circumstances is a 5 RU charge possible, if it is? I've designed my models very carefully to be as small as possible with an eye toward efficiency, but I've never been able to get under ~9 RU for a write.

For example, an item serialized to 334 bytes of JSON reports a charge of 9.52 RU run against the emulator, and I've seen similar numbers in production. Session consistency, no crazy indexing or any unusual config.

Does the mythical 5 RU write exist, and how can I get one? Should an update be considered a write?

P.S. If it matters, I'm using the .NET v4 preview3 SDK currently, although I assume SDK shouldn't impact RU charge...

Answer (score 1):

The RUs will dependent on factors like Indexing, Consistency, Data Replication
You should be able to get

- 1RUs for read
- 5RUs for write
- 10RUs for update(Upsert)
- 5 RUs forDelete

with below settings

- Always have partition key in your Query. Make sure u don't have cross partition query(If possible share your JSON Structure and choice of partition key
- Indexing: Indexing consumes significant RUs. Go to Containers-> Settings. If you don't need indexing u shall disable it with below settings

  {
  "indexingMode": "none",
  "automatic": false
  }
- Data Replication: Go to Settings-> Replicate Data globally. Disable MultiWrite region
- Consistency: Go to Settings -> DefaultConsistency. Set data consistency to eventual.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question. I've already done what is implied by the docs to get 5 RU writes and don't see that in actual practice. The question is whether the docs reflect realistic expectations. Can you provide a screenshot showing an actual write in the 5 RU range?

Comment: I'm able to achieve 5RU range. log from my write operation:

4.95 RUs for creating 1 doc With ThroughtPut as 400RUs
Completed successfully.
Press any key to exit.

DM me @elambaruthi in twitter if you need further help.

Comment: Interesting, could you share the code and data that achieves this?

Comment: `const { item, requestCharge } = await client.database(databaseId) .container(containerId).items.upsert(itemBody)`

I've the following settings: Consistency: eventual Indexing: 

`{ "indexingMode": "none", "automatic": false, "includedPaths": [], "excludedPaths": [] }` @NoahStahl

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you're lowering the consistency and eliminating indexing, neither of which makes sense as a default assumption. Indeed the docs page states that "write costs are applicable when using the default session consistency level", which implies the expectations apply to default settings.