# Azure CosmosDB getting CreateItem charge down to 5 RU how?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to figure out why my `CreateItem<T>` returns a request charge of 7.05 RU for inserting a simple object with 5 properties, less then 1KB including the id and partition key. Its just a default container, with default indexing etc.

The documentation says it should be 5 RU. I've tried to use the `ItemRequestOption` to disable returning the object, disable indexing for that item etc. but it stays at 7.05 RU. I've also tried changing the consistency level of the account but nothing changes.

A `ReadItem` on id and partition key returns with a RU charge of 1.0 as expected and a RU of 2.9 if run as a query.

I'm a little annoyed at the 7.05 RU cost for the CreateItem since its a 41% increase in RU cost over the 5 RUs. Enabling TTL jumped the RU cost to 7.65.

What is the best way to diagnose these kind of issues? I've tried looking at the response diagnostics but its not really helpful.

Comment: Without seeing any specifics (e.g. are your properties spatial types? string? numeric?; are you passing an ID? Allowing Cosmos DB to generate an ID for you?), it's hard to tell why you're seeing a 7RU cost. Are you using direct/tcp, or gateway? Also: which document are you referring to, regarding the 5RU expected create-cost? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I asked the same question. From my experience the docs aren't realistic on this, as I've never achieved 5 even with the simplest item. You could try lowering consistency to eventual as well as disabling indexing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387676/cosmos-db-5-ru-writes-possible

Comment: I agree @NoahStahl i lowered consistency to Eventual and removed all indexing and got it to 4.95, with indexing the RU went right back up again. The docs are misleading as the standard is everything is indexed and consistency is session level.

Comment: I agree, docs should assume defaults and call out if something is true only with certain config.

Comment: The reason the docs show the cost with indexing off is because when indexing is on, the shape of the data can result in large variations in RU charges.

Comment: @MarkBrown It would be great if that sentence were added to the docs, following the 5 RU sentence. :)

Comment: Yeah, we've discussed this before. I'll take this back to the team. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RU consumption on write operations will be heavily impacted by your [indexing policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy).

By default `CosmosDB` container will have indexing enabled for the whole document (each property). If you replace it with specific paths which are used heavily in queries, it can significantly improve performance of write operations as well as reduce consumption costs.

Also please note that there is no guarantee in RU consumption per document in query: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units). It will vary based on index, partition keys, cardinality of partitions, geo-replication, "fan-out" during execution etc.